# Should I take $|ex|=1$ value?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Test the convergence of the series 
$$
x+\frac{2^{2} x^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{3^{3} x^{3}}{3 !}+\frac{4^{4} x^{4}}{4 !}+\cdots $$
Assume $x>0$ and examine all possibilities.

My approach:

Using ratio test I am getting

$$
L=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| = |e.x| >1 $$
 Can I conclude the series is divergent?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! How do you know $|\mathrm ex|>1$? This depends on $x$, and you easily deduce the radius of convergence.

Comment: your comment is not clear.And by replacing n->(n+1),and then taking the ratio u will get L=|e.x|

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You can't say $|\mathrm e x|>1$ if you don't know $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For x = 1/e ; U can go for a ratio test and by then u will find the series will come as a divergent one
$c=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}}$
Let,
$b_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{n^{1 / 2}}$
So,
$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}$
$ \frac{b n}{a_{n}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2nπ}}}=\sqrt{2π} \neq 1$
${b_n}$  & ${a_n}$ have similar char. 
 By p-series test* we can tell ${b_n}$ is divergent.
Hence $a_{n}$ is divergernt

*p series test: 
For the series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{p}}$
The $p$ -series converges if $p>1$
The $p$ -series diverges if $p \leq 1$
here p = 1/2

Answer (score 0):

Careful : you have to check for $x>0$ what is the limit of $\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_nx^n}\right| = \left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}x\right|$. This is equal to $\left|\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n(n+1)}x \right|$ with limit $|ex|$ Thus the limit is $<1$ if and only if $x < 1/e$. Then the radius of convergence is $1/e$. You have to check manually for $|x|= 1/e$ if it converges.

Comment: Here it is asked to determine is the series is convergence or not? If u take it as a converging series  then u must take x<1/e. But is not it clear that for x>0 ; |ex| > 0

Comment: If $ x>0$, then $|ex| = e x >0$. I don't get what you're talking about. The series depends on $x$ thus determining if it is convergent is exactly determining for which value of $x$ it converges.

Comment: No need to be agressive. Moreover, your question isn't that clear : read again what you asked, it is not at all a question about the last case. Then I already answered for that : it is convergent for all $x$ such that $|x| <1/e$, divergent for all $x$ such that $|x| >1/e$, and for $|x| = 1/e$, I said you have to check it manually. Then, what I did not say was : for $x=1/e$ it is divergent (check with Stirling formula). For $x= -1/e$, it converges because of the alternating sum.

Comment: i AM not aggresive.I am sorry if u mind anything.